# Position :after relative to :before

Tags: html, css, css-position, pseudo-element

Let's say I have an input that is displaying a pseudo-element based on a certain data attribute, and positioning it directly above the input so it acts as a label. The label works as intended, but I want to customise it based on additional parameters, specifically, if the input has the "required" class, I want a red asterisk to be displayed next to the label. Is it possible to position an :after pseudo-element relative to the :before pseudo-element?

Here's an example:

```
.flex-form .field[data-label]:before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -16px;
}

.flex-form .field.required[data-label]:before {
    content: attr(data-label) " *";
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #404040 0%, #404040 89%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 90%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #404040 0%, #404040 89%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 90%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #404040 0%, #404040 89%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 90%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #404040 0%, #404040 89%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 90%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

This will give results like this for example, where type is not required but level is, but will only work optimally for average-length label names, as when the label name is too small, it will only partially fill the asterisk red:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:after` can't be relative to `:before` as Traver and Pons said.

But there is a **workaround** with `display: flex;`, `flex-flow: row wrap;` and `order`:

```css
.flex-form {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}

.field {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-form .field select {
  display: block;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  order: 2;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-form .field[data-label]:before {
  content: attr(data-label);
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  order: 0;
}

.flex-form .field.required[data-label]:after {
  content: "*";
  display: block;
  order: 1;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form class="flex-form">
  <div class="field" data-label="Type">
    <select>
      <option>Item</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="field required" data-label="Level">
    <select>
      <option>Level 1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I like it! I'll mark this as an answer as it does exactly what was requested.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to position an :after pseudo-element relative to the :before pseudo-element? Answer is no. The one is before the Element and the other after and not nested.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. The offsets of an absolute/fixed positioned element can be only relative to its parent. That parent can be immediate one or n-th level.